# jQuery script works, just not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, wordpress

## **So I have edited my code now to the following:**

I have been struggling to get this script functioning, as I am pretty new to jQuery. I got it to work work as is should. But as soon as I include the php file to my WordPress installation, then it is not working.

```
<?php
include 'arter.php'; 
?>

<form action="" id="searchForm">
    <label>Art :</label>
    <input list="arter" name="art">
    <datalist id="arter">
    <?php echo $art;?>
    </datalist><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Søg">
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // now you can use jQuery code here with $ shortcut formatting
    // this will execute after the document is fully loaded
    // anything that interacts with your html should go here

$("#result").append( "loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {

        var species = $("input:first").val();

        var posting = $.post( "resultat.php", { art: species });

            posting.done(function( data ) {
           $("#result").html( "Data indlæst: " + data + "<br>" );
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $( "#result" ).append( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});

});
</script>
```

Now the added part below helps me seeing when the call finishes. Loading the page seperately and the call handles and executes just as it should. But loading the page through Wordpress then is just handles the basics. All submit actions are not handled by wordpress, and the code below just continues to execute in a loop.

> $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
>       $( "#result" ).append( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );

resultat.php:

```
<?php
include 'con.php';

// error_reporting(-1); // reports all errors
// ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // shows all errors
// ini_set("log_errors", 1);
// ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");

// set the PDO error mode to exception
// $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function resultat($conn) {

        if ($_POST['art'] == '*') {
            $sql = "SELECT `id`, `navn`, `team`, `art`, `vaegt`, `dato` FROM `indvejninger` ORDER by `art`, `vaegt` DESC";
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT `id`, `navn`, `team`, `art`, `vaegt`, `dato` FROM `indvejninger` WHERE `art`=:art ORDER by `art`, `vaegt` DESC LIMIT 10";    
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("$sql");
        $stmt->bindParam(':art', $_POST["art"]);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<TR> <TD>" . $arr['navn'] . "</TD>";
            echo "<TD>" . $arr['team'] . "</TD>";
            echo "<TD>" . $arr['art'] . "</TD>";
            echo "<TD>" . $arr['vaegt'] . "</TD>";
            echo "<TD>" . $arr['dato'] . "</TD></TR>";
            }
     }    

?>

    <div id="resultat">
    <TABLE style="width:100%" id="result">
    <TR> <TD>Navn:</TD> <TD>Team:</TD> <TD>Art:</TD> <TD>Vægt:</TD> <TD>Dato:</TD></TR>
    <?php resultat($conn);  ?>
    </TABLE>
    </div>
```

I really hope somebody is able to help me figure out this issue?

Comment: Try jQuery noConflict so that it wont conflict. Checkout the link - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Okay, so adding that did not help me, but I am getting a little more information now.

Comment: As Wordpress has a lot of other things going on, it is normal that `ajaxComplete` is triggering frequently. You should make your selectors specific: for the form `$("#searchForm")`, for the input: `$("input:first", this)`. Also `jQuery.noConflict();` seems more logical than `$.noConflict();`. In your result.php, the `<?php resultat($conn);  ?>` generates `print($arr)` outside any `tr` and `td`: that is invalid in HTML. (the good part is that you use prepared statements!)

Comment: Yeah my ajaxComplete is only for debugging at this stage.

I removed the `print($arr)` as it was a error from previous debugging. 

I have been trying to replace `$("input:first")` with `$("#art")` but never got it working, that is why I switched.

Still I cannot figure out why WP is not posting my request to resultat.php.

Comment: If your current page is not `resultat.php`, make sure you have it in the `action` attribute of your form. If it still does not work like that, please update your question with the latest modifications to your code.

Comment: It is not, the page it started calling from is sresult.php, with the code above, then posts to resultat.php.